# Heroku rake db:migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Im trying to rake my heroku app.

I ran the logs and this is what I get.

```
dhcp-v12-201774:staplesounds mattthomas$ heroku run rake db:migrate

Running rake db:migrate on musicfinal... up, run.2067
 ▸    ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000
dhcp-v12-201774:staplesounds mattthomas$ heroku logs

2016-02-11T03:49:26.683947+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:49:26.683947+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:20.892163+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:20.892163+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.454068+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach DATABASE resource by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.454068+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.778790+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.861786+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fc99da3 by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.861786+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:22.235257+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-02-11T03:50:22.235266+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-02-11T03:50:24.263214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 52747 -e production`
2016-02-11T03:50:29.824709+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-11 03:50:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-02-11T03:50:29.824725+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-11 03:50:29] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-02-11T03:50:29.825057+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-11 03:50:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=52747
2016-02-11T03:50:30.076895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-11T03:50:31.502816+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:33.860069+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: Awaiting client
2016-02-11T03:50:34.290992+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-11T03:51:03.862924+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2016-02-11T03:51:04.566425+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: State changed from up to complete
2016-02-11T03:51:04.556094+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: Process exited with status 128
2016-02-11T03:51:29.022012+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:51:34.869016+00:00 heroku[run.8794]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-02-11T03:51:35.464019+00:00 heroku[run.8794]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975105+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160204020529 CreateSongs: migrating ======================================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975125+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- create_table(:songs)
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975127+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0086s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975127+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160204020529 CreateSongs: migrated (0.0087s) =============================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975128+00:00 app[run.8794]: 
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975129+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022634 ActsAsTaggableOnMigration: migrating ========================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975130+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- create_table(:tags)
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975130+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0066s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975131+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- create_table(:taggings)
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975131+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0099s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975133+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_index(:taggings, :tag_id)
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975133+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0094s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975134+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_index(:taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context])
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975134+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0070s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975135+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022634 ActsAsTaggableOnMigration: migrated (0.0332s) ===============
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975135+00:00 app[run.8794]: 
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975136+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022635 AddMissingUniqueIndices: migrating ==========================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975137+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_index(:tags, :name, {:unique=>true})
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975138+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- remove_index(:taggings, :tag_id)
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975137+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0083s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975138+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0030s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975139+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- remove_index(:taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context])
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975140+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0053s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975142+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0071s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975143+00:00 app[run.8794]: 
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975144+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0128s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975142+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022635 AddMissingUniqueIndices: migrated (0.0240s) =================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975141+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_index(:taggings, [:tag_id, :taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context, :tagger_id, :tagger_type], {:unique=>true, :name=>"taggings_idx"})
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975143+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022636 AddTaggingsCounterCacheToTags: migrating ====================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975146+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022637 AddMissingTaggableIndex: migrating ==========================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975144+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_column(:tags, :taggings_count, :integer, {:default=>0})
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975145+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022636 AddTaggingsCounterCacheToTags: migrated (0.0351s) ===========
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975148+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0101s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975146+00:00 app[run.8794]: 
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975147+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_index(:taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context])
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975148+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022637 AddMissingTaggableIndex: migrated (0.0102s) =================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975149+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022638 ChangeCollationForTagNames: migrating =======================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975150+00:00 app[run.8794]: 
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975150+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205022638 ChangeCollationForTagNames: migrated (0.0022s) ==============
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975149+00:00 app[run.8794]: 
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975151+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205024602 DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ================================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975151+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- create_table(:users)
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975152+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0269s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975153+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975153+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0114s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975154+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975154+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0119s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975155+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160205024602 DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.0505s) =======================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975155+00:00 app[run.8794]: 
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975156+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160208210640 ActsAsVotableMigration: migrating ===========================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975156+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- create_table(:votes)
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975157+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_index(:votes, [:voter_id, :voter_type, :vote_scope])
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975157+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0078s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975158+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0108s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975158+00:00 app[run.8794]: -- add_index(:votes, [:votable_id, :votable_type, :vote_scope])
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975159+00:00 app[run.8794]:    -> 0.0060s
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975159+00:00 app[run.8794]: == 20160208210640 ActsAsVotableMigration: migrated (0.0250s) ==================
2016-02-11T03:51:39.975160+00:00 app[run.8794]: 
2016-02-11T03:51:40.965744+00:00 heroku[run.8794]: State changed from up to complete
2016-02-11T03:51:40.921160+00:00 heroku[run.8794]: Process exited with status 0
2016-02-11T03:54:23.806665+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:54:26.593029+00:00 heroku[run.2067]: Awaiting client
2016-02-11T03:54:27.023636+00:00 heroku[run.2067]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-11T03:54:56.595702+00:00 heroku[run.2067]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2016-02-11T03:54:57.366547+00:00 heroku[run.2067]: State changed from up to complete
2016-02-11T03:54:57.351789+00:00 heroku[run.2067]: Process exited with status 128
dhcp-v12-201774:staplesounds mattthomas$
```

I've looked at people with the same errors and I cant seem to get it to work I've tried

```
dhcp-v12-201774:staplesounds mattthomas$ heroku run:detached rake db:migrate

Running `rake db:migrate` detached... up, run.8794
Use `heroku logs -p run.8794 -a musicfinal` to view the output.

dhcp-v12-201774:staplesounds mattthomas$ heroku logs
2016-02-11T03:49:26.683947+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:49:26.683947+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:20.892163+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:20.892163+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.454068+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach DATABASE resource by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.454068+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.778790+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.861786+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fc99da3 by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:21.861786+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:22.235257+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-02-11T03:50:22.235266+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-02-11T03:50:24.263214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 52747 -e production`
2016-02-11T03:50:29.824709+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-11 03:50:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-02-11T03:50:29.824725+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-11 03:50:29] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-02-11T03:50:29.825057+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-11 03:50:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=52747
2016-02-11T03:50:30.076895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-11T03:50:31.502816+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:50:33.860069+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: Awaiting client
2016-02-11T03:50:34.290992+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-11T03:51:03.862924+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2016-02-11T03:51:04.566425+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: State changed from up to complete
2016-02-11T03:51:04.556094+00:00 heroku[run.5073]: Process exited with status 128
2016-02-11T03:51:29.022012+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by mattcthomas@me.com
2016-02-11T03:51:34.869016+00:00 heroku[run.8794]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-02-11T03:51:35.464019+00:00 heroku[run.8794]: State changed from starting to up
```

Thank you so much!

Here's the [github](https://github.com/mattietea/musicappFINAL) link, I'm not sure how much that helps but...

Thanks again. Sorry, I'm pretty new to rails!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be about your firewall issues.

Heroku docs states that: -

> Timeout awaiting process The heroku run command opens a connection to
>   Heroku on port 5000. If your local network or ISP is blocking port
>   5000, or you are experiencing a connectivity issue, you will see an
>   error similar to: $ heroku run rails console Running rails console
>   attached to terminal... Timeout awaiting process You can test your
>   connection to Heroku by trying to connect directly to
>   rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com on port 5000 using telnet. A successful
>   session will look like this: $ telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com
>   5000 Trying 50.19.103.36... Connected to
>   ec2-50-19-103-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com. Escape character is '^]'. If
>   you do not get this output, your computer is being blocked from
>   accessing our services. We recommend contacting your IT department,
>   ISP, or firewall manufacturer to move forward with this issue.

You can do a `heroku run` and then do a `telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000` to see if your computer is blocking the connection.

Comment: Youre right! Thank you Jefferson. I ended up having to use a hotspot on my phone. So annoying haha. My dorm must block that port or something? Not sure.